# What does "mufe" mean?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Using vortaro.net, I found this definition for "prepucio" : "Haŭta refaldo, mufe ĉirkaŭanta la penisan glanon". I understood the meaning, but I don't know what "mufe" is. Vortaro.net doesn't have it, and I didn't find something satisfying on the Internet.

So, I'm asking you: What does "mufe" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage of vortaro.net is that as soon as you type something in the search field, it gives you word suggestions. If you begin to type *muf* immediately a list of words unfolds: *mufi, mufo, mufli*, etc. The final *e* in *mufe* clearly indicates the word is an adverb (*mufi* is a verb and *mufo* a noun). The important thing is to distinguish the root of the word, in this case *muf*. Other online dictionaries (like [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/)) don't have real-time suggestions, so you have to search different variations of the word based on the root in order to find it: *mufe, mufa, mufi, mufo*. In [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) you will only find *mufo*. The advantage of ReVo is that it gives translations in other languages. In this case *mufo* is *[muff](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muff)*, a warm tubular covering for the hands. Accordingly, ***mufe ĉirkaŭanta*** is ***surrounding like a muff***.

Comment: Ooh. I didn't think about looking for muf. I copy-paste mufe. ^^. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Mufo" is a muff (like a glove you stick yours hands in from both sides). So "mufe" would just be "like a muff".